# PHP/MySql Undefined index: id When retrieving Data from MySql table

Tags: php, mysql, sql

I'm   trying to retrieve some data from the MySql table. But when I run the query, It showing **Notice : Undefined index: id**. But when I run the same query in SQLyog it is showing the correct result. Without any error.

Query :

```
SELECT id,temp_name,added,updated FROM `projtemp` WHERE `user_id`='0000000001'
```

Out from SQLyog :

[image]

Error From Firebug Console :

```
<b>Notice</b>:  Undefined index: id in <b>C:\xampp\htdocs\xxx\yyy\zzz\aaa.php</b> on line <b>61</b><br />
```

Php Code which I executed :

```
try {
        $paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT id,temp_name,added,updated FROM `projtemp` WHERE `user_id`='$uid'", $options);
    } catch (paginationException $e) {
        echo $e;
        exit();
    }
```

**Update :**

```
       if ($paginate->success == true) {
        while ($row = $result->fetch_assoc()) {
            $temp=array();
            $temp['id']=$row['id'];   // In this line I'm Getting Error Line-61
           $temp['tname'] = $row['temp_name'];
            $temp['added'] = $row['added'];
            if ($row['updated'] == '') {
                $temp['updated'] = 'Never';
            } else {
                $temp['updated'] = $row['updated'];
            }
            $data['data']=$temp;
        }
```

Please any one help me to solve this issue....

Comment: Is your pagination class retrieving the SQL data as an enumerated or an associative array?

Comment: show us precisely you aaa.php file on line 61, here is the PHP error whit a missing array key.

Comment: @james, insert a `if (!array_key_exists('id',$row)) {var_dump($row); die('hard');}` line 61.

Comment: @ regilero it is `returning` `hard`

Comment: And the `var_dump($row); ` isn't displaying anything?

Comment: @ Mark Baker Sorry for late. The `var_dump($row);` Not executing at all

Answer (score 0):

Try this, you don't need enclose with '' for integer field

```
$paginate = new pagination($page, "SELECT id,temp_name,added,updated FROM `projtemp` WHERE `user_id`=$uid", $options);
```

Answer (score 0):

The error you're getting is not about your SQL query. It's about array processing. I assume you're using ID to step through an array later in your PHP code? Look there for the error.

Comment: I have updated my question can you please check that. I didn't find such conflict anywhere.

Comment: The issue, then is with `$row['id']`. There's something wrong with how your array is being fetched, but from the code available here, I can't see it. Can you post all of the code for the pagination class?

Comment: Also, why is `user ID` enclosed in what appear to be quotes? Unless I'm mistaken (I'm used to PHP/Microsoft SQL), that's unnecessary and may be part of your problem if your DBMS is trying to do a `where` clause comparing two different string literals. That will always return false.

Comment: `link  For Pagination.php `https://drive.google.com/file/d/0B8pmOvAprIC9UjM2NXBia3hhOTA/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Honestly, without being able to work with all your code and debug it, I can't find exactly where the problem is coming from. But it's definitely an array index problem, and definitely related to `$row['id']` on that line. You may want to ensure there's actually data in `$result`, use `count()` to ensure that the `$row` array actually has elements in it, etc. Walk through every step of the process and check to make sure you're getting what you expect.

Answer (score 0):

In my DB worked this query:

```
"SELECT `id`, `temp_name`, `added`, `updated` FROM `projtemp` WHERE `user_id`=$uid"
```

or

```
"SELECT * FROM `projtemp` WHERE `user_id`=$uid"
```

but I not see in your table user_id

Comment: That is `resultant` table not complete set.

Answer (score 0):

in your function `fetch_assoc()` from where you are retrieving data, Fetch a result row as an associative array, a numeric array, or both. in your case, you should write

```
if ($row = mysql_fetch_array ( $result, MYSQL_BOTH )) {
 $id=$row[0];
}
```

as your id in your table is at the 0th location. [Here](http://php.net/manual/en/function.mysql-fetch-array.php) you can read in details.